# Check if date falls between two other dates

Tags: python, merge, lookup

Edit: Added more data to the table

I have two dataframes in Python: df1:

| Date | Company |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-04 | Apple |
| 2020-01-03 | Apple |
| 2000-01-03 | Apple |

and df2:

| Start | End | CEO | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-05 | Tim Cook | Apple |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-05 | Bill Gates | Microsoft |

I would like to add a new column to my first DataFrame with the CEO name from df2. I would like to do that by checking if the date of df1 falls between the two dates of df2. How can I do that or is there even an easier way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at pandas.merge_asof.

Example data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2022-01-04", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2022-10-22"],
                    "Company": ["Apple", "Apple", "Microsoft", "Company"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Start": ["2022-01-01", "1997-09-16", "1975-04-01", "2022-10-23"],
     "End": ["2022-01-05", "2000-01-06", "2000-01-01", "2022-10-23"],
     "CEO": ["Tim Cook", "Steve Jobs", "Bill Gates", "Me"],
     "Company": ["Apple", "Apple", "Microsoft", "C"]})

df1
        Date    Company
1 2000-01-01      Apple
2 2000-01-01  Microsoft
0 2022-01-04      Apple
3 2022-10-22    Company

df2
       Start        End         CEO    Company
2 1975-04-01 2000-01-01  Bill Gates  Microsoft
1 1997-09-16 2000-01-06  Steve Jobs      Apple
0 2022-01-01 2022-01-05    Tim Cook      Apple
3 2022-10-23 2022-10-23          Me          C


# make sure to have datetime columns
df1.Date = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date)
df2[["Start", "End"]] = df2[["Start", "End"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# make sure your dfs are sorted
df1.sort_values("Date", inplace=True)
df2.sort_values("End", inplace=True)
```

end then use

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on="Date", right_on="End", by="Company", direction='forward', allow_exact_matches=True)

        Date    Company      Start        End         CEO
0 2000-01-01      Apple 1997-09-16 2000-01-06  Steve Jobs
1 2000-01-01  Microsoft 1975-04-01 2000-01-01  Bill Gates
2 2022-01-04      Apple 2022-01-01 2022-01-05    Tim Cook
3 2022-10-22    Company        NaT        NaT         NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer works. As you speculated, I do have multiple rows in my first dataframe. Should have mentioned that earlier. I adjusted the table. How would that change your answer?